# How to set PSR logger version 3 within PHPWord PDF renderer

Tags: php, composer-php, mpdf, phpword

I have PHP 8.2. with PHPWord and MPDF, installed via composer. I do not know how to properly set psr logger version. The error is: My code is:

```
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/local/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/PDF.php');
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF);
```

The error is:

> [ErrorException] E_COMPILE_ERROR Declaration of
> Psr\Log\NullLogger::log($level, Stringable|string $message, array
> $context = []): void must be compatible with
> Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::log($level, $message, array $context = [])
> (0) .../www/local/vendor/psr/log/src/NullLogger.php:26

It seems the composer loads an old PSR version. There is a trait PsrLogAwareTrait. How must I use it with PHPOffice to eliminate the error?

Comment: Which version of mpdf/psr-log-aware-trait do you have installed? you need mpdf/psr-log-aware-trait 3.x to use psr/log 3.x.

Comment: How did you installed psr/log? Can you show the composer.json?

Comment: Why not update `psr/log` if you are facing any problem with it?

Comment: The trait is version 3, snd psr/log is also version 3. It looks as if there is another log version, which takes precedence.

Comment: "It looks as if there is another log version" - what have you tried ot resolve that problem? Where are you stuck? Why not open the linked file to check what it contains?

Answer (score 0):

In composer.json I added "psr/log": "^1.1" in the "require" section. The conflict has been gone.

Comment: Keep in mind that this requires a pretty outdated version of `psr/log`. That might block the installation of other current packages